# Visual studio code, compiling and running in single command

Tags: c++, json, bash, clang, visual-studio-code

I have specified a pre-launch task to compile c++ code before launching in the launch.json file.

The build command is outlined in my tasks.json file:

```
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "bash",
"isShellCommand": true,
"args": ["-c"],
"showOutput": "always",
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "g++",
        "isBuildCommand": true,
        "args": [
            "g++ /Users/user/OneDrive/Programming/TicTacToe/TicTacToe.cpp -o /Users/user/OneDrive/Programming/TicTacToe/a.out"
        ],
        "showOutput": "always"
    }
]
```

The output of this when I run this is that I receive a clang error:

```
clang: error: no input files
```

I'm not sure why this is happening as when I copy paste this bash command to terminal it works, but for some reason I am getting clang error from visual studio. Can anyone familiar with clang figure out what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the string passed included the taskname for some reason.

It worked after I addded

```
"suppressTaskName": true
```

to tasks.json